# AWS Lex AMAZON.DATE slot type parsing the date in US format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lex

A lex intent have a slot with type AMAZON.DATE

If I enter the date like 11.02.2019 then it is processing the date in mm.dd.yyyy format, but my customers in Europe region, it supposed to process the date in dd.mm.yyyy format.

I am using Javascript AWS SDK and in the PostText call setting "x-amz-lex:time-zone": "Europe/Dublin" in requestAttributes, but LEX doesn't seem to use this.

```
var params = {
    botName: 'mybot',
    botAlias: 'dev',
    userId: 'testuser-1',
    inputText: 'check 11.02.2019',
    requestAttributes: {
        "x-amz-lex:time-zone": "Europe/Dublin"
    }
};

let res = await new AWS.LexRuntime().postText(params).promise();
```